# How to extract date from string python 3?

Tags: python

How to extract date from string in python 3?

First want to find substring which has date
if it is found then split the element

```
import re
test_list = [["4","list1",'FEE(DR09/01/2019', '1', '13.50'],
["9","list2",'FEE11/01/2019','45.00', '105.00', '0.00', '105.00'],
["7","list3",'2-BED ROOM (09/01/2019 -', '09/01/2019)', '1', '150.00']] 

    subs = r"\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}"
l=[]
for x in test_list:
    for item in x:
        if re.search(subs, item):
            l.append(item)
print(l)
```

Expected Output:

```
[["4","list1","FEE(DR","09/01/2019", '1', '13.50'],
["9","list2",'FEE','11/01/2019','45.00', '105.00', '0.00', '105.00'],
["7","list3",'2-BED ROOM ( ','09/01/2019',' -', '09/01/2019',')', '1', 
'150.00']]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i updated my ocde please see again

Comment: @pyml Why does last sub-list in your expected have dates with parenthesis? Shouldn't they be `'2-BED ROOM (',  '09/01/2019', ' -',  '09/01/2019'`?

Comment: sorry by mistake i forget to separate now i edited my output please see again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re.split` with capture group:

```
import re
test_list = [["4","list1",'FEE(DR09/01/2019', '1', '13.50'],
["9","list2",'FEE11/01/2019','45.00', '105.00', '0.00', '105.00'],
["7","list3",'2-BED ROOM (09/01/2019 -', '09/01/2019)', '1', '150.00']] 

subs = r"(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})"

res = []
for l in test_list:
    sub = []
    for s in l:
        sub.extend([i for i in re.split(subs, s) if i])
    res.append(sub)
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[['4', 'list1', 'FEE(DR', '09/01/2019', '1', '13.50'],
 ['9', 'list2', 'FEE', '11/01/2019', '45.00', '105.00', '0.00', '105.00'],
 ['7', 'list3', '2-BED ROOM (',  '09/01/2019', ' -', '09/01/2019', ')', '1', '150.00']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work just for your specific case

```py
...
for element in test_list:
    for index in range(len(element[2])): 
        if ord(element[2][index]) > 47 and ord(element[2][index]) < 52:
           element.insert(3,element[2][index:]
           element[2] = element[2][:index] 
           if len(element[3]) > 10:
               element.insert(4,element[3][10:])
               element[3] = element[2][:10]
           break          
...
```

but if you want function that get date from string just put second for in function

Answer (score 0):

Extract the date in given string using python3:

by the following code:

```
from pygrok import Grok
input_string = input()
date_pattern = '%{YEAR:year}-%{MONTHNUM:month}-%{MONTHDAY:day}'
grok = Grok(date_pattern)
a=grok.match(input_string)
for key in a.keys():
    print((str(a[key])+'-'),end='')
```

Input:monkey 2010-07-10 love banana

Output:2010-07-10